# I cannot req.body to my mongoose from a form., only some data is coming

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

I am trying to turn a static website to dynamic website. For that I am using express-hbs.
I req for 3 thing, here they are.

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    title: {type: String, require: true},
    content: {type: String, rqeuire: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
```

And here is my hbs code,

```
                <div class="row">
                        {{#each posts}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="blog">
                                <div class="blog-img">
                                    <img src="img/blog2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-content">
                                    <ul class="blog-meta">
                                        <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="writer">{{title}}</span></li>
                                        <li><i class="fas fa-clock"></i><span class="writer">{{date}}</span></li>
                                        <li><i class="fas fa-comments"></i><span class="writer">13</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                                    <p>{{content}}</p>
                                    <a href="blog-single.html">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        {{/each}}
```

And my router code;

```
router.post("/test" , (req,res) => {
    Post.create(req.body)
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

But to my mongoDB Compass, only date is coming.
Title and content actually came to my database for one time, but when i post another title and content, nothing came. Only date.

Comment: There is no form in the code you provided

Answer (score 2):

You have a misspelling in your Mongoose schema. To require a field use [`required`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), not "require" (or "rqeuire").

```js
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help but the problem solved when i move the;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
upper than other codes in my app.js, also i fix the problem you just showed me, thanks again.